# Apollo 3, Meteor and "Cannot await without a Fiber"

Tags: meteor, apollo-server

I'm been struggling for days now to update my Meteor app to use Apollo 3. I'm blocked on a very frustrating problem every time a resolver accesses Mongo:

```
"stacktrace": [
  "AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION] [ERR_ASSERTION]: Cannot await without a Fiber",
  "    at awaitPromise (/Users/Tim/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.12.0.acrhc3.4u34++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:75:12)",
  "    at Promise.await (/Users/Tim/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.12.0.acrhc3.4u34++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:60:12)",
  "    at SynchronousCursor._nextObject (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:1118:38)",
  "    at SynchronousCursor.forEach (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:1132:22)",
  "    at SynchronousCursor.map (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:1142:10)",
  "    at SynchronousCursor.fetch (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:1166:17)",
  "    at Cursor.<computed> [as fetch] (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:920:44)",
  "    at MongoConnection.findOne (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:827:56)",
  "    at Collection.findOne (packages/mongo/collection.js:358:29)",
  "    at loginWithToken (app/api/auth/server/resolvers/mutation/login-with-token.ts:16:16)",
```

I have tried everything that I can think of, including:

Wrapping the `apollo-server-express middleware` inside `Meteor.bindEnvironment` before attaching it to the connect handler

Wrapping every resolver function inside `Meteor.bindEnvironment` before calling `makeExecutableSchema`.

I'm out of ideas. If I downgrade to Apollo Server 2.25.2 it works perfectly. Is anyone else here having this issue?

Comment: I haven't worked with Apollo yet, but bindEnvironment doesn't wrap things in a fiber. You could try using `Meteor.wrapAsync` instead.

Comment: Actually it does: https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#bind-environment

Comment: Oh interesting. Another question: are you using `await` in your own code or is that in the package itself?

Answer (score 0):

**Version 2:**

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getLink: (obj, { id }) => LinksCollection.findOne(id),
    getLinks: () => LinksCollection.find().fetch(),
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: async ({ req }) => ({
    user: await getUser(req.headers.authorization),
  }),
});

server.applyMiddleware({
  app: WebApp.connectHandlers,
  cors: true,
});
```

**Version 3:**

- add async to all resolvers queries
- add server.start() function

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getLink: async (obj, { id }) => LinksCollection.findOne(id),
    getLinks: async () => LinksCollection.find().fetch(),
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: async ({ req }) => ({
    user: await getUser(req.headers.authorization),
  }),
});
server.start().then(() => {
  server.applyMiddleware({
    app: WebApp.connectHandlers,
    cors: true,
  });
});
```